# R.drawable.exit library missing?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on a project where we have been given data collected from an Android app. The data is messy so I want to get the app working in a controlled setting. I have the original java source code and the manifest but not the ADK.

I'm working in Eclipse using the Android ADT. However, I'm new to Eclipse and Java and am having trouble compiling. Installing some libraries like Javamail helped get rid of most of the errors but some persist.

The remaining errors are all related to the class R. For example:

```
R.drawable.exit
R.drawable.playgreen
R.xml.mainprefs
```

The error Eclipse gives for all of them is the same: "playgreen cannot be resolved or is not a field". I've looked these fields up on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html. The field "R.drawable.exit" is not listed although "R.drawable" is.

Am I still missing a library? If so how can I find it?

Comment: These are resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Make sure you have the *drawable.exit*, *drawable.playgreen* and *xml.mainprefs* files in your resources folder. This means that in your resources folder you need *drawable* and *xml* folders (if they don't exist just create them) and have the specified files inside them. Then, rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.drawable.exit` and the others are referencing drawables (ie pictures) that would be located within your *res/drawable* folder. The same thing for the `R.xml.mainprefs` is referencing an xml file in the *res/xml* folder. Without those resources in their respective folders you will continue to get errors.